# How to locate the input tag as per the HTML provided through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Please what locator do i use for the below. I have tried Xpath and CSS Selector but no luck.

```
<input type="password" 
       class="input-block-level ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" 
       placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" ng-trim="false"
       required="" ng-disabled="isLogging" 
       ng-hide="changePassword" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  "input.input-block-level.ng-dirty.ng-valid.ng-valid-required[ng-model='password']"
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  "//input[@class='input-block-level ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required' and @ng-model='password']"
  ```

**Note**: The element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, ensure that you interact with the element inducing *WebDriverwait*.

Comment: I tried both locator provided by you but still did not work, see the error below: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"input.input-block-level.ng-dirty.ng-valid.ng-valid-required[ng-model='text']"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: @Catia make sure u are sreaching for element in correct SearchContext

Comment: @Catia As per the html you have shared the attribute is `ng-model="password"` and accordingly my answer contains `@ng-model='password'` but your error trace logs contains **`[ng-model='text']`**. Can you cross check once again please?

Comment: [ng-model='text'] this belong to the username field and ng-model="password" to the password one.

Comment: @Catia The html within your question is about the field with attribute `ng-model="password"`. How can my answer work for some other field? If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new request as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: This is the latest error as per your request: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"input.input-block-level.ng-dirty.ng-valid.ng-valid-required[ng-model='password']"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: @Catia Did you check the **Note** I have added about the element being Angular element? Did you induce WebDriverWait?

Comment: Ok its working now with the WebdriverWait. Brilliant thank you

Answer (score 0):

For style class `ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required` are inserted automatically by angular compiler after angular complete compile the source code. So your locator should not rely on these style class.

```
1) Using Java as script language

   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Password']"))
   // or
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']"))

2) Using python as script language

   dirver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Password']")
   // or
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")
```

Comment: Please see below the error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[placeholder='Password']"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)